# Did an SR-71 Blackbird airbase have a plaque regarding the valley of the shadow of death?

Tags: military

A common meme around the internet involves a quote from a supposed plaque in front of an [SR-71 Blackbird](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_SR-71_Blackbird) airbase.

[image: Image of stealth plane with text "Though I Fly Through the Valley of Death..I shall Fear No Evil. For I am at 80,000 Feet and Climbing! (Sign over the entrance to the old SR-71 operating base Kadena, Japan)"]

The meme seems to be [extremely popular on the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=sr%2071%20valley%20of%20death%20quote&oq=sr71%20valle&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i13i512j0i390l4.4128j0j4&client=ms-android-verizon&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8), but I can't seem to find an original source.

Most sources I've found online source it to the [Kadena Air Base](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kadena_Air_Base) in Okinawa, Japan.

Is there any verification to this attributed quote?

Comment: So was it a "plaque in front of the base" or a "sign above the entrance"? Underneath this [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/flightsim/comments/607nw1/though_i_fly_through_the_valley_of_death_i_shall/) account of working with the SR-71 is this short comment: *Sign over the entrance to the old SR-71 operating base Kadena, Japan. **XP-10.5 SR71**. Thats it, no other addons*.

Comment: I don't know, I've seen both stories.

Comment: There are lots of photos of Kadena base entrance, and its signs, and lots of citings of the quote, lots of pictures of SR-17 with the quote, yet no pictures of the alleged actual sign or plaque, and in the Reddit post I linked, the guy who was actually on the Blackbird doesn't mention it.

Comment: Japan? Oh this is obviously wrong. [Death Valley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Valley) is in California.

Comment: @WeatherVane do you have a picture available?  i would accept that as an answer

Comment: Pictures of Kadena base entrance are easy to find on Google images, with signs, and one showing a canopy over the entrance without any signs. But that doesn't mean there was no sign when the SR-71 was operational there. I think 'evidence' would be a former aircrew who served there, who can say "that was BS".